# Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin/lib/database'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I was working on my firestore functions. It went fine until today's flutter upgrade. After upgrade "firebase deploy" is not working anymore:

```
    $ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'project-id'...

i  deploying database, storage, firestore, functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/username/Desktop/projects/project/functions
> eslint .

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  database: checking rules syntax...
✔  database: rules syntax for database project-id is valid
i  firebase.storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
⚠  [W] undefined:undefined - Ruleset uses old version (version [1]). Please update to the latest version (version [2]).
✔  firebase.storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
i  firestore: reading indexes from firestore.indexes.json...
i  cloud.firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
✔  cloud.firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  storage: latest version of storage.rules already up to date, skipping upload...
✔  firestore: deployed indexes in firestore.indexes.json successfully
i  firestore: latest version of firestore.rules already up to date, skipping upload...
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin/lib/database'
Require stack:
- /Users/user/Desktop/projects/project/functions/src/profile.js
- /Users/user/Desktop/projects/project/functions/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

Tried posts with similar topics on stackoverflow but they didn't work for me. Tried "npm install" from both project and functions directory, I beleive I have latest firebase-admin package, but still getting this error. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was, one of the 'required' files inside 'functions' directory was updated during upgrade. This line was added:

```
const { admin } = require('firebase-admin/lib/database');
```

Commented this line and deploy is working fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Do
 `flutter get packages`
And tell me if it fixed or not thanks.

Comment: I believe you meant "flutter pub get". Yes, tried that, but no luck.